# Interpretations of Non-Inferiority

Tags: statistical-significance, proportion, non-inferiority

I'm having some trouble really groking non-inferiority for risk difference in a two sample binary proportion.

Let $p_1$ be the risk of the outcome from the standard of care and let $p_2$ be the risk of the outcome from a new intervention.  To establish non-inferiority, the confidence interval for old minus new (i.e. $p_1-p_2$) for the risk difference should not cover the non-inferiority margin from below, assuming that the risk in the new intervention is greater than the risk in the control group.

In a picture, assuming the black line is the non-inferiority margin...

[image]

So am I to believe that non-inferiority boils down to determining if the risk difference is compatible with the non-inferiority margin (where compatibility is defined as "is within confidence interval")?

Comment: Can you lay out the mathematics that you are trying to interpret?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's basically correct. The point of a non-inferiority trial is to provide strong evidence that a new treatment is not importantly worse than an existing treatment. "Strong evidence" means "incompatible based on the confidence interval" and "not importantly worse" means "worse by no more than the specified margin".

Two minor points:

- the opposite of non-inferior is "not non-inferior" rather than "inferior"; a treatment that's not non-inferior can still potentially be better than the comparator.
- the black line that the confidence interval has to exclude is not the margin, the margin is the *difference* between the estimated benefit of the existing treatment and the black line.